# Aplicacion creada con express

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express

tengo un problema al instalar el modulo de express en manjaro. Cuando ingreso el comando `npm i express` obtengo el siguiente resultado:

```
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall symlink
npm ERR! path ../mime/cli.js
npm ERR! dest /run/media/exxe/66AC-0444/Proyectos/web/backend/node_modules/.bin/mime
npm ERR! errno -1
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, symlink '../mime/cli.js' -> '/run/media/exxe/66AC-0444/Proyectos/web/backend/node_modules/.bin/mime'
npm ERR!  [OperationalError: EPERM: operation not permitted, symlink '../mime/cli.js' -> '/run/media/exxe/66AC-0444/Proyectos/web/backend/node_modules/.bin/mime'] {
npm ERR!   cause: [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, symlink '../mime/cli.js' -> '/run/media/exxe/66AC-0444/Proyectos/web/backend/node_modules/.bin/mime'] {
npm ERR!     errno: -1,
npm ERR!     code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!     syscall: 'symlink',
npm ERR!     path: '../mime/cli.js',
npm ERR!     dest: '/run/media/exxe/66AC-0444/Proyectos/web/backend/node_modules/.bin/mime'
npm ERR!   },
npm ERR!   errno: -1,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'symlink',
npm ERR!   path: '../mime/cli.js',
npm ERR!   dest: '/run/media/exxe/66AC-0444/Proyectos/web/backend/node_modules/.bin/mime',
npm ERR!   parent: 'backend'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/exxe/.npm/_logs/2020-05-15T16_23_16_651Z-debug.log
```

La verdad no se como solucionarlo, ya intente con el comando sudo y tambien darle permiso a las carpetas, alguien le sucedió lo mismo

Comment: Intenta cambiar el `owner` de la carpeta `/node_modules/`

Comment: Ya lo intente pero el mismo resultado

Comment: Estas instalando en alguna particion relacionada con windows? O trabajas solo en manjaro?

Comment: en el disco tengo dos sistemas operativos windows 10 y le instale manjaro

Comment: Ok, posiblemente estés utilizando una partición de windows para guardar tu proyecto. En cuestion de permisos windows y linux no se llevan bien, asi que te va a dar siempre ese error. Copia tu proyecto a una particion de linux y prueba de nuevo.

Comment: Tenes razón copie mi proyecto a una partición de linux y funciono correctamente gracias

Comment: Tuve un problema parecido. En mi caso el proyecto no estaba en una partición de windows sino en otro disco duro. Copie y pegue el archivo en una partición de Linux y pude instalar express. Muchas gracias!